# Better way to print out data from only the first index in an array full of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, foreach

Option 1:

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
    echo $foo[$i]->attribute;
    echo $foo[$i]->attribute2;
}
//shows obj1's attribute and attribute2
```

Option 2:

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
$first_foo = array_shift($foo); /* now we only have the first index in the new array */
foreach ($first_foo as $object) {
    echo $object->attribute;
    echo $object->attribute2;
}
//shows obj1's attribute and attribute2
```

Option 3:

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
$first_foo = $foo[0] /* now we just have an object, obj1 */
echo $first_foo->attribute;
echo $first_foo->attribute2;
//shows obj1's attribute and attribute2
```

I used Option 3, but all of these feel kinda lacking... how would you do this? Is the loop in options 1 and 2 worth it if you feel like easily pulling the first two instead of one later on? I.e. pulling the latest news article vs. pulling the latest two etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated?

Loops, `array_shift()`, ... it's all not neccessary.

You gave the solution yourself:

```
$foo[0]->attribute
```

Another one would be

```
reset($foo)->attribute
```

On your edit:

If you want to write the code so it is flexible later, do

```
$need = 1; // the variable number of elements you need
for($i = 0; $i < $need; $i++)
    echo $foo[$i]->attribute;
```

Comment: The extra complexity was because I was thinking it might be convenient if say, later on you wanted to pull 2 or 3 off the front. The extra complexity allows a little more robustness.. but at what cost? I edited the question a bit. Solid answer obviously.

Comment: Added a simplistic `for` loop to fit your needs.

Comment: I guess that's where the trouble is. Does this mean the `for` loop is really the best way to do it? I would have thought no... but Option 3, like the option you wrote seems somewhat 'hardcoded'.

Comment: `array_shift()` on the other hand would return an array containing only one element (effectively useless), and has to be in a loop itself. `foreach` is a really complicated mechanism (AFAIK more complex than `while` and `for`) - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works).

Comment: I think `for` literally is the best way to do it here.. would not have thought...

Answer (score 1):

The two iterations aren't needed in this case. I would just take your option #3 with a little less code.

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
echo $foo[0]->attribute;
echo $foo[0]->attribute2;
```

Comment: Well it isn't. @OP in this case I guess you'll have to loop with foreach.

Answer (score 1):

assuming:

```
$b = [0,1];
$c = [2,3];
```

let:

```
$a = [$b,$c];

$first_elem = array_shift($a);

print_r($first_elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to get more than 1 from array_shift which returns null after array is empty

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
while($obj = array_shift($foo))
   echo $obj->attribute;
```

your option 2 can be changed to

```
$foo = array($obj1, $obj2, $obj3);
foreach ($foo as $object) {
    echo $object->attribute;
    echo $object->attribute2;
}
```

why don't use use it that way?